# Red5 Media Server + jwPlayer not working as expected

Tags: iis, video-streaming, red5

hi i'm running the red5 media server on my win 2003 server, it's assigned to its own IP-address. i've set up a testcase using jwplayer for streaming a video, unfortunately it doesn't work as expected (works locally, ports are open, when using port 5080 i can run the red5-demos from external)

i'm using the following settings for jwplayer:

```
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'test.flv',
    'protocol': 'rtmp',
    'streamer': 'rtmp://myserver.com:1935',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '470',
    'height': '320'
  });
```

the problem is that jwplayer shows up an error:

```
Server not found: rtmpt://myserver.com:80
```

although i've defined protocol rtmp on port 1935, jwplayer is trying to use rtmpt on port 80? any ideas what's wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think JWPlayer tries by default to fallback to RTMPT on port 80.

So that message:

```
Server not found: rtmpt://myserver.com:80
```

could be translated in the humen readable message:

```
I tried to connect to rtmp://myserver.com:1935, was not able to connect, 
falled back to rtmpT (rtmp over HTTP Tunneling to bypass firewalls) 
on port 80. But still failed
```

Sebastian

Comment: thanks! i checked the porttester and found out that it fails on ALL ports :(( although i opened them all .. any ideas?

Comment: You should check the red5 log file if there was an issue/Exception during startup. If that is fine you have to configure the Firewall of your Windows server.

Comment: already tried that - i switched the firewall off temporarily .. without success :(